# Try catch block doesn`t catch error in node.js

Tags: node.js, try-catch

```
class AuthController {
    static methods = {
        GET: {
            '/auth/signup': {
                func: AuthService.signUp,
                response: (data, res) => {
                    res.statusCode = 200;
                    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
                },
            },
        },
    };

    static use(req, res) {
        const route = this.methods[req.method][req.url];
        if (!route) {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ message: 'Not found 404!' }));
            return;
        }
        try {
            const data = JSON.parse(req?.body?.data || '{}');
            const result = route.func({ ...data });
            route.response(result, res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err, 'here');
            res.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
            res.end(JSON.stringify(err.message));
        }
    }
}


class AuthService {
    static async signUp({ login, password }) {
        if (!login || !password) throw new BaseError(400, 'kl', 'Custom error');
     }
}
```

It shows the error in console but try catch block doesn't see it.
[Here is the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Va1.png).
I don't know what the reason is because the function which throws error is inside of the block. Help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace back that you attached tells you exactly what the problem is and what you need to do:

`This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()`

You can't catch an exception thrown by an async function with a `try..catch` block outside of that function, because script execution reaches the catch block before the async execution is finished. You therefor have to use `.catch(..)` instead:

```
const result = route.func({ ...data }).catch((err) => {
    console.log("catched error: ", err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one issue.  You have declared `signUp()` to be `async`.  That means it always returns a promise and it means that any `throw` operations inside it reject that promise that it returns (the exception doesn't propagate synchronously).  But, when you attempt to call it here:

```
 const result = route.func({ ...data });
```

You don't `await` it so when `signUp()` rejects, the promise goes into `result`, but nobody ever handles the fact that the promise rejected and you get `UnhandlePromiseRejectionWarning` from the system.

I can't see the whole overall design (of all the other routes), but perhaps you just need to add `await` to this:

```
 const result = await route.func({ ...data });
```

And, you would have to make `.use()` be `async` also.

---

Or, if `signUp()` doesn't actually need to be `async`, then just remove the `async`  from its declaration and the `throw` will be synchronous (instead of being turned into a rejected promise) and your `try/catch` will catch it then.

Comment: @alexey - Did this work for you?